# Как отключить отправку http-заголовка "Expires"?

Tags: apache, nginx, php

(В apache, в nginx, в php.)
отключенный expires заставляет браузер отправлять "if-modified-since" (для того чтобы сервер посылал 304 при необходимости)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для nginx как-то так

```
server {
    location / {
       expires off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в .htaccess

```
ExpiresActive Off
```

Это для апача, nginx не в курсе.

Comment: а в какую секцию добавляется?